# getting textbox focus after messagebox in chrome browser

Tags: silverlight

when I show a messagebox and after it make a textbox focused It dose not work in chrome browser but in IE Firefox and others I works, I googled it but without result, can sb help?

```
MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            Textbox.Focus();

            return;
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem.  We had to use the Dispatcher to send the focus request asynchronously.

```
textbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => textbox.Focus());
```

We've also seen issues with certain Silverlight runtimes disabling the parent screen when a dialog box is opened, or rather not re-enabling the parent once the child dialog closes.  The following line of code forces the main screen to be enabled.  It's possible the textbox isn't receiving focus because the entire screen is actually in a disabled state.

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue(Control.IsEnabledProperty, true);
```